# Entity Framework Mapping values are not returned

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

**Problem:**

I have a `DbContext` class created from EF using a database-first approach. But when accessing the `User` details, I am unable to validate.

**Output**

The code is working but the validation is not successful. Provided the `DbContext` and `Validation` classes:

**AlumniConnectEntities.cs**

```
    namespace Test
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
        using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
        using System.Linq;

        public partial class AlumniConnectEntities : DbContext
        {
            public AlumniConnectEntities()
                : base("name=AlumniConnectEntities")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<Alumnus> Alumni { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Validation.cs**

```
     public class StudentValidation
        {
                AlumniConnectEntities dbConnection = new AlumniConnectEntities();

                public bool CheckLogin()
                {
                    //bool loginSuccess = dbConnection.Users.Where(x => x.username == "rupee@gmail.com" && x.password == "rupee").Any();


                  var usersList = dbConnection.Users.ToList(); 

                 var loginSuccess= usersList.Where(x => x.username ==  
                 "rupee@gmail.com" && x.password == "rupee").Any(); 
                    return loginSuccess;
                }
            }
```

**Users.cs**

```
 public class Users
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int Role_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Roles Role { get; set; }
    }
```

**Role.cs**

```
public class Roles
    {
        public Roles()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<Users>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string role_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [role_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Users]    Script Date: 04/23/2019 20:50:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [password] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Role_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK__Users__Role_Id__44FF419A]    Script Date: 04/23/2019 20:50:55 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([Role_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([id])
GO
```

[Getting the query when initiating the DBCOntex Class and not getting the property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJkIh.jpg)

[image: EF Table Schema]

Comment: First thoughts are: Can you debug and put a breakpoint at the username and password check? Maybe you can check the values of username and password when they get pulled from DB to see what they contain.
Also, are they hashed or encrypted in the database? Perhaps you need to unhash or unencrypt the values before you can compare them plain text like that.

Comment: Please provide `User` class and `User` table schema then only anyone can identify whether it is related to the maping problem or not.

Comment: I t looks like you are calling the constructor and creating a new connection : AlumniConnectEntities dbConnection = new AlumniConnectEntities();  There is probably code already that made the connection.

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but you can shorten what you have to `dbConnection.Users.Any(x => x.username == "rupee@gmail.com" && x.password == "rupee");` and it will also query faster.

Comment: Is the password hashed/encrypted? You might not be able to validate against plain text.

Comment: I have debugged the application I was able to get the username and password If i use the foreach loop ,but when using the given linq I am unable to get the details...THe password is not hashed/encrypted...

Comment: Not working still...ANy idea how to convert the entity data model to compare the values as given in validation.cs